# How can implement live stripe apple pay in swift? Stripe test key is working fine but not live, how can I fix it?

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, strip, swift4.2, applepay

I'm using stripe apple pay for payment. I have integrated stripe apple pay and it is working fine with test stripe key. But when I use live stripe key it shows an error:

```
Apple pay not completed "total" was not able to complete the payment.
```

I'm following [stripe doc](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) and  [this blog](https://medium.com/@abdul.i.aljebouri/bare-minimum-apple-pay-xcode-9-swift-4-5245bd3dcde4) to integrate apple pay. Done with these steps:

1: [Register for an Apple Merchant ID](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay/apps#merchantid)

2: [Create a new Apple Pay certificate](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay/apps#csr)

3: [Integrate with Xcode](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay/apps#setup)

When click on apple pay button, this code will run:

```
let paymentNetworks:[PKPaymentNetwork] = [.amex, .discover, .masterCard, .visa]

        if PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: paymentNetworks) {
            let request = PKPaymentRequest()

            request.merchantIdentifier = constants.merchantIdentifier
            //request.supportedCountries = ["GB"]
            request.countryCode = "GB"
            request.currencyCode = "GBP"
            request.supportedNetworks = paymentNetworks
            //request.requiredShippingContactFields = [.name, .postalAddress]
            // This is based on using Stripe
            request.merchantCapabilities = .capability3DS

            let total = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Total", amount: NSDecimalNumber(decimal: Decimal(floatLiteral: Double(totalWithDeliveryCharges))), type: .final)
            request.paymentSummaryItems = [total]

            let authorizationViewController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request)

            if let viewController = authorizationViewController {
                viewController.delegate = self

                present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        else {
            self.showAlert("Alert", "Device does not support apple pay.")
        }
```

My output is :-

[image]

```
Apple pay not completed "total" was not able to complete the payment.
```

But actual output is

```
Processing complete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.
[I forget to refresh apple pay merchant id in XCode after stripe apple pay certificate added.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo4Ds.png)

Follow the image and just click on refresh merchant id button to get rid of this error.
Make sure you have added stripe apple pay certificate by following this [step](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay/apps#csr).